# ng-View not showing after adding dependencies in Yeoman Angular

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I just created a new Yeoman angular project. The basic site worked when I started grunt serve. I tried to add new dependencies 'ui.bootstrap' or 'google-maps' to main module than the ng-View not showing.

**index.html**

....

```
<div ng-view=""></div>
```

....

**app.js**

```
   angular.module('clientApp', [
    'ngRoute',
     'google-maps'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {

     $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? More than likely your problem is you have misspelled a dependency in `app.js`.

Comment: Do you have any javascript console error ?

Comment: i've solved the problem by updating "google-maps" to "uiGmapgoogle-maps" with help of Doc [link](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use). actually i was follow this tut [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RdrGWWc_4s) it was old.